# Configuring an A Record for Azure Reserved Instance

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service

I have created a WordPress site on Windows Azure and deployed it. It is a reserved instance, and according to [this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) article, I should be able to get the IP address from the portal in order to configure an A record:

> With an A record, you map a domain (e.g., contoso.com or www.contoso.com) or a wildcard domain (e.g., *.contoso.com) to the single public IP address of a deployment within a Windows Azure hosted service. Accordingly, the lifetime of this IP address is the lifetime of a deployment within your hosted service. The IP address gets created the first time you deploy to an empty slot (either production or staging) in the hosted service and is retained by the slot until you delete the deployment from that slot. You can discover this IP address from within the Windows Azure Management Portal.

I don't see an IP address anywhere in the Windows Azure Portal. Can anyone point me to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** As of 9.17.2012 it is possible to add an A Record to a [azure-web-sites](/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites) instance, follow the [Configuring a Custom Domain name for a Windows Azure Web Site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) instructions on WindowsAzure.com

---

The Article refers to Windows Azure Hosted Service, looking at the terminology you are using (e.g. Reserved) I believe you are using Windows Azure Web Sites.

Windows Azure Web Sites is a service which is managed by Microsoft, because this service is utilizing the Cloud Service infrastructure there is no guarantee as to what the IP Address for your website instance will be, you will need to utilize CNames.

My colleague Brady Gaster has put together a [blog post](http://www.bradygaster.com/redirection-with-windows-azure-web-sites) on how you can setup CNames to your Windows Azure Web Sites.

You can also read the post on WindowsAzure.com which describes [how to use CNames with Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/).

Comment: Yes, you're correct - using Windows Azure Web Sites. I had seen Brady's post (and others) about using CNAMES, but I had hoped to be able to use an A record so I could redirect *.domain.tld, not just www.domain.tld.

Comment: Brady's post talks about DNSimple who offers a service which looks like it's simply doing a HTTP 301 redirect from the DNS registry to the www address of the site. If you've been using bare domains this should resolve properly. You could luck out like David Ebbo [http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/07/using-naked-domain-with-windows-azure.html] and have naked domains "just work"